# Force next page load in iframe to break out

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, firefox-addon

I have an iframe which loads the new tab page. On click of the thumbnail though it loads within that iframe. I want any consequent load in the iframe to load in `window.top`. Is this possible without individually setting the thumbnails to use `target=_blank`. Because if user removes a thumbnail it is populated by another which won't have this `target` attribute set.

I gave this javascript and html5 as the same knowledge applies to breaking out of frame.

If there is no javascript/html5 solution for this these were my thoughts on options:

- Add a `unload` event to the iframe. However in the unload event object I can't find the new url it is going to
- Use `http-on-modify-request` observer and on modify check if the `loadContext` window is the iframes contentWindow and if so then abort that request and load it in the `window.top`, i just think this is overkill for something that should be so simple

Comment: I'm actually quite interested in this as well. Subsequent page loads do not have to be by element of `<a>` so the `click` solution is not preferred by me. Is there any other ideas to force next load? Perhaps more on the `unload`? From the add-on/privileged scope an elegant solution must exist. Please undo your accepted solution so hopefully others may provide other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a single `click` event listener on the whole document or window.
- Then when the event listener is called, inspect target.
- You may need to traverse the `.parentElement` tree until you find the `<a>`.
- If successful `.preventDefault()` the event.
- And then, Do whatever you want<sup>(tm)</sup>.

Example:

```
addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  while (target && !target.href) {
    // Find the parent <a>, if any
    target = target.parentElement;
  }
  if (!target) {
    // Nothing found;
    return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(target.href);
  // window.top.location = target.href; ?!
});
```

Tested this in the Console, and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks man I up vote for side solution. Although I can't do this way. Because it misses if user uses keys. Some addons use keys to navigate here too. Also I was hoping to use this break from frame technique else where too. But for right now the solution I'm using is mutation observer, every time a thumbnail is added i query selector it's a element and set its `target=_parent` thx so much tho

Comment: Switching to a link by keyboard and then hitting `enter` will actually generate a click event as well. So keyboard navigation is covered as well. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh no way I didn't know that. I actually didn't test I just assumed lol ok thanks man!